# The quantum capacity of a trace-decreasing CP map

Tags: quantum-information

Assume a qubit quantum channel (trace-preserving CP (==completely positive) map) $\mathcal{N}:C^2\to C^2$ whose quantum capacity is known. Now I construct a new channel $\mathcal{M}:C^2\to C^{2+n}$ where $n>0$:
$$
\mathcal{M}=p\mathcal{N}\oplus(1-p)\mathcal{C},
$$
where $\mathcal{C}$ is an arbitrary channel $C^2\to C^n$, whose form I don't need to know, and $0\leq p\leq1$. Assume that I have access just to the two-dim output subspace of $\mathcal{M}$ given by the image of $\mathcal{N}$. So effectively, I constructed a new CP map $\mathcal{M'}:C^2\to C^{2}$ that is trace-decreasing (since $p\leq1$).

Here is my question:
What si the quantum capacity of $\mathcal{M'}$ ?

Here is my answer:
Irrespective of $n$, I can assume that $\mathcal{M'}$ can be written as
$$
\mathcal{M'}=\mathcal{E}\circ\mathcal{N},
$$
where $\mathcal{E}:C^2\to C^3$ is a qubit erasure channel
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho)=p{\rho}\oplus(1-p)\rho_{fixed},
$$ 
where  $\rho_{fixed}$ is an input-independent positive operator (density matrix) spanning a one-dimensional subspace. Hence, the quantum capacity of $\mathcal{M'}$ is the minimum of the quantum capacities of $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ (known as the bottleneck inequality).

**EDIT**
Following Shor's comment I wanted to say that the quantum capacity of $\mathcal{M'}$ will be **bounded** from above by the quantum capacities of $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{E}$.

Do you agree?

Comment: Have you looked at what happens with classical channels?

Comment: No, what exactly should I look at?

Comment: Suppose that classically, you have an erasure channel composed with another channel. Do you get this bottleneck behavior? [Hint: ***no***, assuming I understand your question correctly; so why should we see it in the quantum version of the question?] Does the classical proof carry over to the quantum case?

Comment: The bottleneck inequality is an ***inequality***, not an equality.

Comment: Oh, so I was being imprecise, I wanted to say that the capacity of $\mathcal{M'}$ will be less than either of $\mathcal{N}$ or $\mathcal{E}$. Is this statement correct? My main question is whether the whole model for this particular TDCP map as  $\mathcal{E}\circ\mathcal{N}$ is correct.

Comment: I think by adding the erasure symbol, you've effectively turned a trace-decreasing map into a trace-preserving map. But maybe this is an argument about definitions.

Comment: So I will take it as that you agree. Thx! On a general note, it seems to me that any TDCP map can be written as some channel followed by a qubit erasure channel followed by a restriction to an output subspace. So the quantum (or classical) capacity can be bounded from above